# Should you encrypt a LogonId/LoginId/Username in a database?

Tags: database, database-design, encryption

Does anyone have recommendation on whether or not a logonid/loginid/username (whatever you may be referring it to as) should be encrypted in your database.

Up to recently we always encrypted passwords, which made sense, but we never encrypted the loginid, but a few of my colleagues highlighted that it was just too easy to identify for them to just blank out their password (or copy it to the clipboard) and login as the specific user.

Our database is secured. It is only accessible to the NETWORK Service, an application pool and/or the db owner, so the only people who could potentially do this would be administrators or dba's.

So my argument was that if you could not have a certain level of trust with these people, you had a bigger issue but I felt it didn't require your loginid to be encrypted.

Am I right or wrong on this? What are you thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see why you should encrypt username, how you will read the username if you encrypt it?

Comment: Just by encrypting the username before passing it to a stored procedure but I feel it's an overkill to be honest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encrypt username/logonid but I don't think that would add much more security in your context than not encrypting them. If your goal is to prevent admins/dba's and people who have access to the backend database from impersonating users (by resetting passwords etc.), the best way would probably be to implement **multi-factor authentication**.

In this scenario, your users would provide multiple authentication parameters for example:

- A password which is hashed or encrypted in the database and also a token key code for example which would be time generated (via a token they would hold), or
- A password and elements of personal information, for example the first/third/last (these positions change) letters of their security question which would be encrypted in your database.

Also you may want to consider implementing a robust login/logout audit trail so that suspicious logins can be traced back. This database should maintain its integrity (ie. admins should not be able to modify its contents easily) and you can achieve that by using checksums and/or storing the audit tables in a database that is accessible by a different group of admins.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. The multi-factor is an interesting concept I guess and I never thought off that... Similar to my online banking mechanism but having said that but we'd have to make sure you could never have the personal info blank as we still allow users to have blank password if they want to. It's rare but it is still done. As for the robust audit trail, and while we have it, how robust would it be if you can't rely on your administrators/dba as they technically could just as easily modify this. Anyway, I've got a few ideas to work off, so thanks for that.